# Converting CCYYMMDDHHMMSSsss into java using joda time format

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-format, tuxedo

Hi I have Date time format with century I was trying to convert it into string using Joda date time format but I am getting junk data while converting it I am not sure why this is happening

Code

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("CCYYMMDDHHMMSSsss");
String str = date.toString(fmt);
System.out.println(str);
```

this is the output

```
20170103��0100���
```

but output should come like this

```
20160620091223711
```

Comment: I don't even use Joda time, and I can tell you that pattern string is nothing like correct. Review [the documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Comment: Yes, your pattern is completely wrong, see pattern description. For example, patterns are usually case-sensitive. And why do you think that hour, minute, second and fraction of second (what you want?!) have any meaning when your input is just a calendar date without time part?

Comment: Also, `LocalDate.now()` returns the date as of now, I'm not sure why you're expecting the output you've given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the current date and time to be formatted, you should try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("CCYYMMddHHmmssSSS");
String str = fmt.print(dt);
System.out.println(str);
```

Here, a `DateTime` object is used, the pattern is according to specification and the print method of `DateTimeFormatter` is used.